# Break out of a loop on Back button

Tags: java, android, for-loop, android-activity, back-button

I have an Android app with two activities. In the child of the two activities, I run an infinite `for` loop in my `run()` function.

I want the activity to return to the previous view on under either of two conditions:

1. The current calendar second reaches `HIGH_SEC` (59)
2. The user hits the <kbd>Back</kbd> button

The first of the two is satisfied by the following code:

```
Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {            
        for (;;) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            if (cal.get(Calendar.SECOND) == HIGH_SEC)
                break;
            System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        finish();
    }
};
```

Currently, when the user hits the <kbd>Back</kbd> button, the app freezes up. I assume that's because the activity is stuck in the infinite `for` loop. Does anyone know how to check for the <kbd>Back</kbd> button so that I can have my code react appropriately?

Comment: One way of doing it to define a global boolean. You need to catch back button press event and set the boolean to true. In your for loop, check if boolean is true then break the loop else execute the code.

Comment: I have not attained a working solution yet. Maybe by the end of the week. Else, sometime later.

Comment: Ok! Post back if you have any issues!

Answer (score 1):

You can use onBackPressed()

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    run = false;
}
```

It is discouraged however to use the back button for anything that is not expected as normal behaviour. Perhaps you should make a dedicated UI button instead?

Instead of using `for(;;) {}` it is also, imho, cleaner to use `while(myBoolean) {}`

EDIT: 
Full example

```
private static volatile boolean run = true;

Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {            
        while (run) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            if (cal.get(Calendar.SECOND) == HIGH_SEC)
                break;
            System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        finish();
    }
};

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    run = false;
}
```

Comment: i'm going to try your method along with Mudasser Hassan's idea of keeping track of a boolean. onBackPressed will trigger the boolean which will break the while loop. thanks!

Comment: No probs, good luck! My "while(true)" statement was to show that it is possible to use a boolean, should have made it clearer :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868167/android-volatile-not-working must use flag as volatile private static volatile Boolean backFlag;

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can capture the button press event. You can use it to your needs(i.e.) back button event check.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // Do whatever you want here.
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Else, you can simply use this:-

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
   // Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: thank you this is going to helpful at some point, though I don't think I'm going to use it to solve this issue